# Edit Django Admin JS Sheet Element

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms

I am using this js form to select users:

```
<style>
        .selector {
          float: none;
          display: block;
          height: 330px;
        }

        .selector-available,
        .selector-chosen {
          float: left;
          width: 380px;
          height: 330px;
          text-align: center;
          margin-bottom: 8px;
        }

        .selector ul.selector-chooser {
          float: left;
          width: 22px;
          height: 330px;

          background-color: var(--selected-bg);
          border-radius: 10px;
          margin: 10em 5px 0 5px;
          padding: 0;
        }

        .selector input[type="submit"] {
          display: block;
          clear: both;
        }

        .selector h2 {
          font-size: 15px;
        }


        textarea {
          display: block;
          width: 450px;
        }
      </style>
```

Which results in a page rendering:

[image]

I am trying to put the remove all button as well as the directional arrows between the Available users and Selected Users boxes so everything is even but, I am not sure how to do so. Could someone point me in the right direction?